# How to find shutter count in my Canon 1100D?

Tags: shutter, shutter-actuations, canon-1100d

I have Canon 1100D camera used for some time. Can anyone please tell me how do I check shutter count? I tried googling it. Installed some softwares but none gives the shutter count.

Answer (score 2):

[*Shutter Count*](http://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/) from [Dire Studio](http://www.direstudio.com/) works for me on all of my post-Digic II Canon EOS cameras. Your Canon EOS 1100D is listed as compatible.

Canon cameras released since the end of 2014 do not allow shutter count functionality from the remote control interface and are not compatible with *Shutter Count*.

### Update

**Dire Studios has released ShutterCount version 3 (currently for Mac or iOS only) that can now read the shutter counts for the cameras excluded above, as well as some other more recent models.** From the updated *FAQ* page as of July 2, 2017:

> Q13 - The shutter count is not displayed for new cameras (5D IV, 5DS/R, 1D X II, etc.)
>
> Update to ShutterCount 3.0 or later on your Mac or iOS device. The Windows version will support these cameras later on.

Dire Studios also now offers an add-on [Live View Pack](https://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/live-view-pack/) to their [Shutter Count](https://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/) app that allows one to see Live View stills and Live View movie actuations of the shutters in selected cameras.

For a list of all supported cameras, please see the Compatibility List at the [ShutterCount Tech Specs page](http://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/tech-specs/).

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like Dire Studios is interested in ever updating the Windows version again, due to the high cost of Microsoft licensing. They once had a statement to this effect included in one of the FAQs, but it seems to no longer be there at their site.

As of 22 February, 2018 there has still been no update to the Windows version of *Shutter Count*. In fact, the older version compatible with Windows is no longer offered for sale by Dire Studios.

Comment: @flolilolilo At the time that was written, that was the case. As has been updated in several other similar answers here, at a later time they managed to find a way to work around the new limitations Canon put in place. Even so, they seem to be using another method than the Remote Control interface for cameras introduced since the 7D Mark II.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the most reliable way to find out the amount of shutter actuations for the Canon EOS 1100D (also known in Americas as Canon EOS Rebel T3 and in Japan as Canon EOS Kiss X50) is through the installation of the firmware hack called [**Magic Lantern**](https://magiclantern.fm/).

In my blog post [**How to Check Shutter Count on Canon EOS 1100D (Rebel T3)**](https://www.tamrazyan.com/how-to-check-shutter-count-on-canon-eos-1100d-rebel-t3/) I described the whole procedure in 7 simple steps and there is also an embedded video that walks you through the process. I must warn you that it can potentially damage your camera if something goes terribly wrong, but from my long experience with the Magic Lantern hack on different cameras, I haven't ever experienced any problems.

To my knowledge, it is the only available way to read the shutter count of both standard and the live view modes.

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux distribution, MacOS X, FreeBSD or NetBSD, you can connect your camera via USB cable to your computer and use [gPhoto](http://www.gphoto.org/) command-line interface as follows:

```
gphoto2 --get-config shuttercounter
```

For example, here's what I get on Linux (additionally showing camera model to illustrate that it works for 1100D):

```
$ gphoto2 --get-config cameramodel --get-config shuttercounter
Label: Camera Model                                                            
Type: TEXT
Current: Canon EOS 1100D
Label: Shutter Counter
Type: TEXT
Current: 13613
```

I've actually checked that once I make a shot after this, then turn off the camera and back on, then check again, the counter does increment. So this does appear to be the correct counter.

If you're on Windows, you can try running e.g. an Ubuntu Live ISO image in a virtual machine, passing the USB camera device to the guest OS and doing the above.

Answer (score 0):

[Canon EOS Digital Info](https://sourceforge.net/projects/canon-eos-digital-info/).

This simple to used, FREE, Open Source app worked for me (Canon 6D Mark I), and lists the 1100D in the example screenshots. It is Windows only.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried www.camerashuttercount.com?  Just upload an image...

Comment: This site does not work for the Canon 1100D - it's not among the list of models tested.